# What are the limitations of the Nikolsky-Eisenman (NE) Equation? And what exactly is a more accurate equation to use for modeling selectivity?

Tags: electrochemistry, nernst-equation

I am very curious as to where exactly the Nikolsky-Eisenman (NE) equation fails. I know that the reference I posted here mentions that when the charge of the interfering ion versus the analyte's charge is different, then the equation no longer appears to describe reality accurately. However, I don't understand where the equation might fail on the theorized calibration curves with interferences (assuming we know concentrations of the system as well as all selectivity coefficients).

The reason I am curious is because I built a model of the NE equation in python to attempt to model how each interferent affects the calibration plot of a ion selective electrode (ISE). I used 5 different analytes where two had +1 charges and three had +2 charges. The analyte has a +2 charge. I am curious what equation is more accurate to use to model this type of scenario as I was simply only using the standard NE equation and I couldn't not find the so called permutated or semi-empirical form of the NE equation that claims to be more accurate of reality.

I assuming standard temperatures and conditions for all my simulations and activities = concentrations for simplicity.

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

[image: Selectivity Coefficient and NE equation]

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321532727_Describing_Ion_Exchange_at_Membrane_Electrodes_for_Ions_of_Different_Charge

[image: reference to NE equation failure]

Comment: Please add a proper typed reference citation in place of the image you included.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1002/elan.201700700 

does that work?